# Google SafeBrowsing Lookup API - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to request information about a domain without success; code:

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents('https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=asasd&apikey=MYKEY&appver=1.5.2&pver=3.0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onet.pl%2F');

?>
```

Why isn'tit working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn'tit working?

because wrong url

http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://example.com/

Comment: he is asking about the api access, this is the right safe url. i had the same problem with file_get_contents, solved using curl as @bitanalyzer said.

Answer (score 2):

//function for getting the data from url

```
function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Then get the content using the function call :

```
$returned_content = get_data('your url');
```

get_file_contents() has huge security threat – and many servers have disabled this feature in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

just take a look at the [documentation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

- with URLs, you should use [urlencode()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)
- [fopen wrapper](http://de.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) has to be enabled (same as for [fopen()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php))
- maybe the url is wrong - when i copy your URL and try to open it, i get a pageload-failure.